# Spatial autocorrelation in a correlation maxtrix

Tags: correlation, autocorrelation, spearman-rho, networks

I have obtained species observation data from a spatially dense sampling scheme. I know from previous analyses that there is significant (residual) autocorrelation for some, but not all species of the observation data, which i accounted for in my previous modelling approaches.
I would now want to draw a basic co-occurence network for my observed species, based on basic pairwise Spearman and Pearson correlation. I know that (residual) autocorrelation is actually a real issue for modelling purposes due to altering the degree of freedoms and thus messing up the p-values.

Correlation analysis is technically not a modelling approach, but it does work with p-values. 
Here are my questions:
1. Would you still consider spatial autocorrelation as a nuisance in basic correlation analysis?
2. If so, how would you deal with it? I am think of permuting the correlation function between two pairs of species, because i learned that permutations destroy autocorrelation structures. But that would take much time to calculate and i actually dont know how to reflect the permutations in the final pairwise observation matrix.

Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: Spatial correlation isn't a "nuisance;" it's a fundamental aspect of a model when it appears.  It should be dealt with directly, instead of making it disappear with tricks like permutations.

Comment: You are absolutely right in terms of predictive modelling, and there are many ways to incorporate rsac/sac in models, but how would you incorporate the spatial component in a very basic correlation matrix, in which you basically only want to show which species appear together? Their "together-ness" could be due to observation-independency or not, but regardless they are appearing together.